# nhibernate joins with no relationship between tables

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

```
tableA
------
Aprimarykey,
Afield1,
Afield2,
AfieldtoMatch  

tableB
------
Bprimarykey,
Bfield1,
Bfield2,
BfieldtoMatch
```

There is no relationship between tables. What would be the classes and the hbm file look like if I want the following results?

```
select distinct tableA.Afield1, tableA.Afield2,tableA.AfieldMatch tableB.Bfield1,tableB.Bfield1    
from tableA innerjoin tableB on tableA.AfieldtoMatch=tableB.Bmatchfield
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to join, clearly there is some sort of relationship, though abstract.

Stating an SQL query as the intended results leaves the question still open for interpretation. You should probably map the tables each to separate entities, then you can use HQL or LINQ to join on arbitrary columns when you query.

You might also want to look at the <join> element in the reference: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-join.